# I need to to auto calculate an input field on keyup function on other 2 input field which are created using Accordian

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, accordion

Example: calculate area on keyup of length and breadth. All 3 are defined inside accordion loop.
I can create n no.  to fetch polygon details (which we are doing using accordion because we need collapsible div).We need to auto-calculate the area and show in the input box of area for each polygon at the time of entering l and b.

i tried using keyup function and get the value on each index. it works for normal div but doesnt work when the div is inside accordion class  or(in loop)

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <div>
      length
      <input [(ngModel)]="item.length" (keyup)="functiontocalculate($event)" />
    </div>
    <div>
      breadth
      <input [(ngModel)]="item.breadth" (keyup)="functiontocalculate($event)" />
    </div>
    <div>area <input [(ngModel)]="item.area" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code to the question so that we can help you to debug it.

Comment: <div class = "accordion>
   <div class ="accordion-content">
   <div> length
      <input [(ngModel)]="item.length"
      (keyup)="functiontocalculate($event)"/>
   </div>
   <div> breadth
      <input [(ngModel)]="item.breadth"
      (keyup)="functiontocalculate($event)"/>
   </div>
   <div> area
      <input [(ngModel)]="item.area"/>
   </div>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a calculate value (if it's a simple calculus) you can use

```
<input readOnly [value]="(+item.length)*(+item.breadth) || ''" />
```

NOTE: the "+" before is to convert to number the value. If the result isNaN, show ''.

In this way you neend't use nothing more.

**Update** Well, with this way we don't store the area in "item".

Generally in a submit function we can do

```
this.items.forEach(item=>{
   item.area=(+item.length)*(+item.breadth)
})
```

If we don't want to do this, really we can use the function "keyup", but I prefer use ngModelChange in the way. See that you pass to the function the "item"

```
  <input [ngModel]="item.length" 
         (ngModelChange)="item.length=$event;calculateArea(item)"/>
  <input [ngModel]="item.breadth" 
         (ngModelChange)="item.breadth=$event;calculateArea(item)"/>
<input [value]="item.area" /></div>
```

//and in .ts

```
calculateArea(item:any)
{
   item.area=(+item.length)*(+item.breadth) || ''
}
```

See that the $event in ngModelChange is the value of the input

Comment: how to store this value in ngModel so that i can use it in component. currently its coming blank inside component. if I dont enter it manually

Comment: Could you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76806135/store-selected-checkbox-value-where-the-checkboxdivis-inside-an-accordion-cla   
It is on similar