# store selected checkbox value. where the checkbox<div>is inside an accordion class.This value need to be calculated for every item of accordion

Tags: javascript, html, angular, checkbox, ngmodel

```
isChecked(name){
    let tempI = this.chekcbOxValueArray.findIndex((x)=> x == name)
    return tempI>=0 ?true :false;
}

selectedWorker(name, checked){
    if(checked == true){
        this.a.push(name)
    }
}

onClickOkay(){
    item.workerNamesSelected = a.toString()
}
```

```
<div class="accordion-content">

    <div *ngFor="let item of accordianFields; let i = index">

        <!-- This is 1st item of accordian (chekcbox input) -->
        <div>
            worker Names
            <ng-template #checkBoxPopup>
                <div *ngFor="let worker of workerdataList">

                    <input type="chekcbox" [checked]="isChecked(worker.name)"
                        (click)="selectedWorker(worker.name, $event.target.checked)"
                        [(ngModel)]="item.workerNamesSelected" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button (click)="onClickOkay"></button>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
            <span ngbPopover="checkBoxPopup"></span>

        </div>\


        <!-- 2nd item  -->
        <!-- nth -->

    </div>
</div>
```

I am unable to get value for each item of accordion. The value remains same for all the accordion item -worker name.

Expected result:

for 1st item : some selected worker

for second accordion item : some other selected worker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A input type checkbox only can have two values: false or true. So, a serie of checkboxes only can store an array of booleans

If we want in a variable store an array of values instead of a serie of booleans and we are using template driven form (ngModel) we need to have

1. An array with the list of values: `workerdataList`
2. A Variable: `item.workerNamesSelected`
3. Two functions:

   ```
   isChecked(name:string,item:any)
   {
      return (item.workerNamesSelected || []).indexOf(name)>=0
   }

   checked(checked:boolean,name:string,item:any)
   {
     const oldValue = item.workerNamesSelected || [];
     if (!checked)
         item.workerNamesSelected =item.workerNamesSelected.filter((x:string)=>x!=name)
     else
         item.workerNamesSelected=this.workerdataList.map(x=>x.name).filter(
                 x=>x==name || oldValue.indexOf(x) >= 0)
   }
   ```

Now we can split the `[(ngModel)]` in `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of accordianFields; let i = index">
    <div>
      worker Names
      <div *ngFor="let worker of workerdataList">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          [ngModel]="isChecked(worker.name,item)"
          (ngModelChange)="checked($event,worker.name,item)"
        />{{worker.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

See that in input type checkbox in angular **not** use `[checked]`. All is mannaged by the [ngModel]

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-aueuac?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

NOTE: In the stackblitz I not use an accordeon, but it's indiferent.